JPA Multiple join columns for @ElementCollection with one column having a static value
I'm writing an app with tags, and the tags all go into a tags table with a record_type and a record_id
My annotation in the Kotlin entity looks like this:
@ElementCollection
@JoinTable(name = "tags", joinColumns = [
    JoinColumn(name = "record_Id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
    JoinColumn(name = "record_type", ???) 
])
@Column(name = "tags")
var tags: MutableList<String> = mutableListOf()

What do I put in the ??? spot to use a static value instead of a column ref, like record_type = 'person' for this entity?
This way, I have 1 tags table for all entities that can be tagged.

It sounds like you want a record_type column inserted with a default value when inserting from this relationship - this isn't supported in JPA. I assume you want this table to be able to filter on this value as well so that it can be reused for other classes. IMO you are better off with each having their own table, or mapping it as an entity instead of element collection.
